# create textInput to filter the data in r shiny app

Tags: r

Here I am trying to filter the data based on the textinput as filter where i can enter any variable and filter the data, here i tried the below code

however if i enter subset it does not work, any thoughts will help

```r
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Data"),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
          # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
          fileInput("data",
                      "Upload the data"),
          textInput('tdata', 'filter condition', value = NULL),
          actionButton("saveFilterButton","Filter Values"),
           tableOutput("input_file")
  )    
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
   
   output$input_file <- renderTable({
     # tdata2 <- unique(input$tdata)
     # input$saveFilterButton
     # if(tdata2==''){
     mtcars
     # } 
   })
   
   observeEvent(input$saveFilterButton,{
   output$input_file <- renderTable({
     tdata2 <- unique(input$tdata)
     mtcars %>% filter(tdata2)
   })
})
   
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUaED.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7N9eY.png

Comment: Did you test the code you provided to us? One issue with it is the function sampled doesn't exist

Comment: Thank you I updated the code to replace the sampled() with mtcars, i checked it and it  work.

Comment: Ok, which columns are you trying to filter? all of them?

Comment: yes, for suppose i would like to filter e.g., mpg==21 & cyl==6

Comment: Ok so you want to write an expression that is evaluated within filter function?

Comment: yes, an expression

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254029/discussion-between-jkatam-and-just-james).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `parse` which can take a string as an unevaluated expression and `eval` it within `filter`

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)



# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Data"),
  
  # Show a plot of the generated distribution
  mainPanel(
    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    fileInput("data",
              "Upload the data"),
    textInput('tdata', 'filter condition', value = NULL),
    actionButton("saveFilterButton","Filter Values"),
    tableOutput("input_file")
  )    
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$input_file <- renderTable({
    # tdata2 <- unique(input$tdata)
    # input$saveFilterButton
    expre <- parse(text = input$tdata)
    if(input$tdata != ''){
    mtcars |>
      filter(eval(expre))
    } else {
      mtcars
    }
  }) |> 
    bindEvent(input$saveFilterButton)
  

  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```